# archive manager / file-roller to encrypt & decrypt pgp files

Tags: pgp, file-roller

Is there any way to open/decrypt .pgp files in the gui? It would be great if archive manager was able to do this.

Comment: Is this of any help? https://apps.kde.org/kleopatra/

Comment: ok that pretty much does the job. i can 'open with' kleopatra and save decrypted file